# how to save original position of Imageview and compare it with new position of same Imageview?

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is silly question.
I am developing a puzzle game and code for that is :

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var allImageViews : [UIImageView] = []
    var allCenters : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var emptySpot : CGPoint = CGPoint()
    var originalCenters : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Center point for piece of image for iPhone 5S simulator
        var xCen : CGFloat = 53
        var yCen : CGFloat = 53

        // arrangement of 3*3 piece of images
        for v in 0...2{

            for h in 0...2{
                var pieces = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
                let filename = String(format: "Smile_%02i.gif", h+v*3)
                let Image = UIImage(named: filename)
                let myImageView = UIImageView(image: Image)
                var curCenter : CGPoint = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)

                //adding centerpoint to allCenter array
                allCenters.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint : curCenter))
                myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 106)
                myImageView.center = curCenter
                myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

                //adding all Images in array allImageviews
                allImageViews.append(myImageView)
                self.view.addSubview(myImageView)

                //Increment on X-Axis
                xCen += 106
            }
            //again sex X centerpoint to 53
            xCen = 53
            //Increment on Y-Axis
            yCen += 106
        }
        // romove one piece at index 0
        allImageViews.removeAtIndex(0).removeFromSuperview()
        // we have all 8 imageview and all 9 centerpoints
        self.randomizeBlocks()

    }
    // placing the piece of images randomly
    func randomizeBlocks(){

        // new array that copy centerpoint from allCenters
        var centersCopy: NSMutableArray = allCenters.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

        var randLocInt : Int
        var randLoc : CGPoint

        // loop for all peice of images saved in allImageViews
        for i in allImageViews {
            //Place Images randomly
            randLocInt = Int(arc4random()) % centersCopy.count
            randLoc  = centersCopy.objectAtIndex(randLocInt).CGPointValue()
            i.center = randLoc
            centersCopy.removeObjectAtIndex(randLocInt)

        }

        // for finding empyblock which is at index 0
        emptySpot = centersCopy.objectAtIndex(0).CGPointValue()

    }
    var leftisEmpty : Bool = Bool()
    var rightisEmpty : Bool = Bool()
    var topisEmpty : Bool = Bool()
    var bottomisEmpty : Bool = Bool()


    // touch event
    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var topCen : CGPoint
        var left : CGPoint
        var right : CGPoint
        var top : CGPoint
        var bottom : CGPoint

        let touches = touches.allObjects as [UITouch]
        var myTouch = touches.first

        if let myTouch = myTouch{

            topCen = myTouch.view.center

            // movement to empty block
            left = CGPointMake(topCen.x - 106, topCen.y)
            right = CGPointMake(topCen.x + 106, topCen.y)
            top = CGPointMake(topCen.x, topCen.y+106)
            bottom = CGPointMake(topCen.x, topCen.y-106)

            // Deciding which side is empty
            if emptySpot  == left{
                leftisEmpty = true
            }
            if emptySpot  == right{
                rightisEmpty = true
            }
            if emptySpot  == top{
                topisEmpty = true
            }
            if emptySpot  == bottom{
                bottomisEmpty = true
            }

            if leftisEmpty || rightisEmpty || topisEmpty || bottomisEmpty{


                UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context:nil)

                UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
                myTouch.view.center = emptySpot
                UIView.commitAnimations()
                emptySpot = topCen

                leftisEmpty = false
                rightisEmpty = false
                topisEmpty = false
                bottomisEmpty = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now I am stuck at when the user complete the whole picture how can I compare positions of all the Images so there should be alert message appear and says "Game Is Complete".I have don't have any idea that how can I do that.

Please help me for complete this game.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply maintain a dictionary with object's like @[@"piece1":false,@"piece2":true ...so on]. So when user place a piece of puzzle at right point you could set it's object to true and then check whether all are true or not. If all true then game over.

Comment: can you please edit my code in answer?

Comment: could put up some explanation/comments in your code for my better understanding then I would make changes accordingly.

Comment: Code updated and let me know if you still have problem to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with change and explanation :-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            ........YOUR CODE......


     //READ below.......
     var tagValue: NSInteger = 0  //change it as me typing directly in post.
     var imageDict: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
     var posStateDict: Dictionary<String, String> = [:] //Change it as per swift format.

     var frame: CGPoint = CGPointZero

    for v in 0...2{

        for h in 0...2{

            ........YOUR CODE......

            //......UPDATED.......
            //Now you should also add a tag value to your imageView

            myImageView.tag = tagValue
             myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

             frame = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)
             imageDict.setValue(NSStringFromCGPoint(frame), forKey: NSString.stringWithString("/(tagValue)"));    

             posStateDict[NSString.stringWithString("(d)")] = ["false"]                
             tagValue = tagValue + 1;    //Incrementing tagValue.

        }
                       ........YOUR CODE......
   }
                  ........YOUR CODE......
}

// touch event
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

                  ........YOUR CODE......

        if leftisEmpty || rightisEmpty || topisEmpty || bottomisEmpty{

                  ........YOUR CODE......


            //READ below.......Rest code here.
            //Here you need to get that imageView object which is moved.
            //From that imageView you need to get tag value. 
            //With the tag value you could search it's orignal frame from the imageDict and compare the frame of it.
            //If frame match then set their respective object true in posStateDict dictionary.
            //Now check this dictionary if all true and no false then game is over.
        }
    }
}
```

}

Sorry I wasn't able to code for the part as got some work. Hope this explanation will help you out.

Comment: please can you make code more readable when you get time because I didn't understand  it properly. :(

Comment: I have put a tag //READ below....... so you need to read it out. I haven't made code changes but put up explanation of what to do as I have time constraint. So you need to code that part.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to assign value for frame(X,Y)?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I have updated some initial part for you. Rest I hope you could carry forward and also I am new to swift.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an 3x3 array which holds the number of the current puzzle piece at each position. Initially, this would be

```
var pieces = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

where `0` denotes the empty spot. This array is updated each time a puzzle piece is moved, e.g.
when the piece #3 is moved upwards then

```
pieces = [[3, 1, 2], [0, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

The game is completed if `pieces` is equal to the initial array again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe save the original `imageView` centres in an array then compare this against their new positions?